# Running emulator under Android Studio causes processor temperature rise

Tags: android, android-studio

I have recently migrated to Android Studio on a new machine (Intel i7, 8GB, Ubuntu). When I launch any system image emulator, the cooling fan comes on and I see the /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp show a rise from 32 to 53 degrees.

Is such behaviour normally expected?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised honestly. The Android emulator (and IMO Android Studio too)  is quite an heavy piece of software. Have you tried using [Intel HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)?

Comment: Yes, It has the Linux equivalent and hardware acceleration on.